# sed: performing a replace on N lines after a pattern match

Tags: regex, bash, unix, replace, sed

I'm trying to use sed to perform a replace on only N lines after a specific pattern.

Looking at the sed man page it seems like it should be possible to do using addr1,+N syntax. But I can not get it to work.

```
 <data>
  <variable>DebuggerItem.Count</variable>
  <value type="int">2</value>
 </data>
 <data>
  <variable>Version</variable>
  <value type="int">1</value>
 </data>
```

The replace I am performing finds the numbers in this markup and increments them by 1. It is as follows.

```
sed -r 's/([ ]*<value type=)\"(int)\"(>)([0-9]*)(.*)/echo "\1\\"\2\\"\3$((\4+1))\5"/ge' filename
```

I now want to restrict that replacement to just the N lines after the one containing "DebuggerItem.Count". In my current instance N is 1, but I have another example where I would want to perform this for 5 lines after the matched one, so N would be 5.

It can probably be performed with a more complex replace, but ideally I would like to learn more about using addresses with sed.

Note: I had some trouble with the double quotes in the search replace as I needed to double escape them for the following echo. So the search replace is a little convoluted. My apologies.

Comment: Your big problem is that `xml` data is not aware of lines, so that approach is wrong. If not now I bet you will struggle with it in the near future. You should try with a `xml` parser.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying @Birei sed is probably not the best tool for the job at hand as I'm stream editing an xml file. But I still think the question about the use of the addr1,+N syntax usage is valid. I'm happy to reformat the question to remove instances of <, /, "and > if it helps with providing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Birei; don't do this with `sed`. Nobody expects your XML tools to break if there's a newline added in a harmless place or nodes reordered, and that's exactly the sort of thing that will happen if you use line-based tools for the task. Things would break in horrible ways, and they will probably do it two months after you forgot what you built there and why.

There are plenty of tools that can parse and transform XML sanely. For example, with `xmlstarlet` your problem can be solved like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//data[variable="DebuggerItem.Count"]/value' -x '. + 1' filename.xml
```

Here `//data[variable="DebuggerItem.Count"]/value` is an XPath expression selecting the `value` subnode of a `data` node anywhere in the document  whose `variable` subnode has a value of `"DebuggerItem.Count"`, and `. + 1` is another XPath expression meaning the value of the current node plus one.

See also [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

If you are hell-bent on using `sed`, and rest assured that it will come back to bite you, you can restrict the application of your `s` command to three lines after you found `DebuggerItem.Count` in the file like this:

```
#               new bit            from here it's the same as before.
#       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  vvvvvvv
sed -r '/DebuggerItem\.Count/,+3 s/([ ]*<value type=)\"(int)\"(>)([0-9]*)(.*)/echo "\1\\"\2\\"\3$((\4+1))\5"/ge' foo.xml
```

Comment: Thanks @Wintermute. Much appreciated. Thanks for providing the xmlstartlet alternative as well as a working answer to my original misguided question.